# problema con textContent en Javascript.

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

estoy aprendiendo Javascript y para ello estoy estudiando del libro "Javascript & Jquery de Jon Duckett" , me gustaria saber si estoy haciendo algo mal, segun el libro deberia modificarse el texto del html y colocar el contenido del archivo javascript en lugar de este mediante el textContent o eso pienso yo , pero no sucede nada, me gustaria saber si alguien me puede ayudar con esto, gracias.

```js
 
    var greeting = 'Howdy ';
    var name = 'Molly';

    var welcomeMessage = greeting + name + '!';
    var el = document.getElementByld('greeting');
    el.textContent = welcomeMessage;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Elderflower</h1>
  <div id="content" onclick="">
    <div id="greeting" class="message">Hello
      <span id="name">friend</span>!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Parece que todo está bien, solo que nunca mandas llamar a tu Script, crea una funcion, y ese nombre lo pones  en el evento clic de tu botón, no te pongo el código puesto que no aprenderías. Intenta y editas la pregunta con tus errores.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, coloque todo dentro de una funcion y el script funciono, sos un genio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo veo es que tienes un error en la línea de código:

```
var el = document.getElementByld('greeting');
```

Debería ser:

```
var el = document.getElementById('greeting');
```

Estás usando una `l` en lugar de una `I`.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas llamar a tu script

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="path/to/script.js"></script> <!-- AQUI SE LLAMA AL SCRIPT -->
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Elderflower</h1>
  <div id="content" onclick="">
    <div id="greeting" class="message">Hello
      <span id="name">friend</span>!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```